# Set size for QGroupbox?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyside

I'm new guy, and i start with new simple GUI application, I follow some tutorial on the internet and now i have a trouble with QGroupbox (Pysde).
This is my code :

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide import QtGui,QtCore

class Form(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Form,self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Library')
        self.setMinimumHeight(600)
        self.setMinimumWidth(800)
        self.setMaximumHeight(600)
        self.setMaximumWidth(1100)

        #Groupbox Show Only
        gpShowonly = QtGui.QGroupBox("Show only :")
        gpShowonly.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
        chbx1 = QtGui.QCheckBox("x1")
        chbx2 = QtGui.QCheckBox("x2")
        chbx3 = QtGui.QCheckBox("x3")

        serverlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        serverlayout.addWidget(chbx1)
        serverlayout.addWidget(chbx2)
        serverlayout.addWidget(chbx3)

        configLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        configLayout.addLayout((serverlayout))
        gpShowonly.setLayout(configLayout)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(gpShowonly)
        mainLayout.addStretch(1)


        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

I want it's smaller but it's always full horizontal , I use setGeometry,resize but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

The widgets inside a layout will expand to fill the available space. To prevent this, simply add an expandable spacer to the end of the layout:

```
    serverlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    serverlayout.addWidget(chbx1)
    serverlayout.addWidget(chbx2)
    serverlayout.addWidget(chbx3)
    serverlayout.addStretch()
```

If this makes the widgets too small, you could give them a minimum width:

```
    for widget in chbx1, chbx2, chbx3:
        widget.setMinimumWidth(100)
```

Comment: I can't understand clearly your code, could you explain more or give me more code, please! Thanks you so much.

Comment: @MinhTuanNguyen. The first four lines are exactly the same as your own code. So just add the other three lines, and run it. No other code is needed.